# Directory of Wolfram Language reference tutorials

Tags: documentation

The online reference for the Wolfram Language includes tutorials on various topics. Is there a table of contents or directory containing links to all of these tutorials?

Comment: Use menu `Help | Wolfram Documentation` to go to the `Documentation Center`. Enter `tutorial` in the search field and hit `return`. You will get many pages of links to tutorials along with with short descriptions of them.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Here's a little thing you can use. First the code to compile the TOC:

```
getTutorialURLs[] :=
  SortBy[Length@URLParse[#, "Path"] &]@
   Map[If[FileNameTake[#, {-3}] === "System", "", 
        StringSplit[FileNameTake[#, {-5}], "-"][[1]] <> "/"] <> 
       "tutorial/" <> FileBaseName[#] &]@
    FileNames[
     "*.nb",
     Prepend[
      FileNameJoin@{#["Location"], "Documentation", "English", 
          "Tutorials"} & /@
       Join[
        Association /@
         Thread[
          "Location" ->
           FileNames[
            "*",
            FileNameJoin@{
              $InstallationDirectory,
          "Documentation",
          "English",
          "Packages"
          }
        ]
      ],
    PacletManager`PacletFind["*"]
    ],
  FileNameJoin@{
    $InstallationDirectory,
        "Documentation",
        "English",
        "System",
        "Tutorials"
        }
      ]
     ];
Options[PaneColumn] =
  Join[
   {
    Dividers -> True,
    ItemSize -> Automatic,
    ImageSize -> {Automatic, {Automatic, 250}},
    Scrollbars -> {False, Automatic},
    AppearanceElements -> None,
    Framed -> False,
    FrameMargins -> 0,
    FrameStyle -> Black,
    ImageSizeAction -> "Scrollable"},
   FilterRules[Options[Column],
    Except[Dividers | ItemSize]],
   FilterRules[Options[Pane],
    Except@(
      Alternatives @@ Join[
        Options[Column],
        {ImageMargins, ImageSize, Scrollbars, AppearanceElements}
        ])
    ],
   FilterRules[Options[Framed], Except@(
      Alternatives @@ Join[
        Options[Column],
        Options[Pane],
        {FrameMargins, FrameStyle}]
      )]
   ];
PaneColumn[things_, ops : OptionsPattern[]] := Pane[
   Column[things,
    Dividers -> With[{style = Replace[OptionValue@FrameStyle,
         l_List :> Last@Cases[l, Except[_List], \[Infinity]]]
       },
      Switch[OptionValue@Dividers,
       True, {
        {}, Thread[Range[2, Length@things] -> style]},
       False, {},
       _, style
       ]
      ],
    FilterRules[
     Join[{ItemSize -> 
        If[OptionValue@ItemSize === Automatic, 
         Replace[OptionValue@ImageSize, {
           _Integer | _Scaled | 
             Full | {_Integer | _Scaled | Full, _} :> {1000, 
             Automatic},
           _ :> Automatic
           }]
         ], ops}, Options@PaneColumn], Options@Column]
    ],
   FilterRules[
    Join[{FrameMargins -> {{0, -1}, {1, 1}}, ops}, 
     Options@PaneColumn], Options@Pane]
   ] // If[TrueQ@OptionValue@Framed,
   Framed[#, 
     FilterRules[Join[{ops}, Options@PaneColumn], Options@Framed]] &,
   Identity]
```

Then the interface:

```
PaneColumn[
 Hyperlink[#, "paclet:" <> #] & /@ getTutorialURLs[]
 ]
```

[image]

Each link there will open the docs notebook, e.g.:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, @b3m2a1! It worked like a charm.

Comment: There are 1,001 tutorials (`getTutorialURLs[]//Length`) !

Comment: @Reb.Cabin yeah but *lots* of them are for deprecated components (`GUIKit`, `ANOVA`, etc.) or are out of date (some of the "advanced" LA stuff, other old school operations stuff)